# Can I just copy Windows from one SSD to another and use it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, hard-drive-recovery

To upgrade my windows SSD, can I just use a linux live version and copy the whole content over to the new (and bigger) SSD?

Or are there easier ways? I fear that the boot-sector (and whatever else there could be) won't be copied and I will run into issues.

Comment: If you use `dd`, just make sure you use the `conv=sync` option; otherwise, any read error will render the rest of the copy invalid.

Comment: Clonezilla should work well too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you leave the original drive intact until you're sure everything is working other than lost time there shouldn't be any harm in trying. You can always wipe the SSD and start over again.

You will want to make sure that you copy all of the boot sector/partition and partition structure to the new drive. This can be accomplished with software like Clonezilla but you could also just do it from a Linux live CD/USB system using the `dd` command to copy the entirety of the old drive bit for bit onto the new drive. This all assumes that the new drive is at least as big or bigger than the old drive. Note that after you're done if you want to use the additional space on the drive you'll have to resize/extend your NTFS partition.

Really, this is probably a good opportunity to do a fresh installation of Windows which is what I'd recommend instead. My experience is that you'll spend more time trying to make this work than if you just did a fresh install, reinstalled your applications, and copied your data back over from the old drive to the new one. Because of the way Windows activates on systems now your system should automatically activate even on a fresh installation.

Comment: Funny that such an "easy" request/task is so complicated... :( I probably try the Clonezilla approach or the dd one, since extending disk space isn't that much of a problem as I know it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is called "Bare Metal Restore".
You do full backup to .vhdx file (which is block-oriented copy), boot from PE (Windows disk or MSDART) and then restore it.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/05/12/bare-metal-restore/

I did it several times to move windows to another drive. I then expanded new partition using disk manager.

When booting from PE you may face some troubles using UI restore. In this case you may open console and use wbadmin (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd767786.aspx)

https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc742118(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score -1):

No. You will need to clone it using something like Clonezilla or Macrium Reflect Free. They will also allow you to adjust the partition sizes.

From my personal experience, when only swapping the SSD, there should be no need to re-authorize the windows license.

In rare occasions, one might need to "Generalize" their install before cloning but probably not an issue when simply putting the cloned drive into the same machine.